# Htaccess over right a RewriteRule for some files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

So right now it rewrites the page.php to the root of the site.  I want this to be the case, except for when there is a file in the root of the domain, then I want it to show that file instead.

It does this automatically already except you have to include the .php on the end, so like: http://domain.com/contact.php

I want it like: http://domain.com/contact

The last line of the htaccess code does that except it will only work in subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]
```